# Shifting spectrogram on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have signal which starts at time -1 seconds.

However, when plotting the spectrogram, the first bin edge starts at 0 (midpoint at 0.25) How do I change this so that my data is represented accurately when plotting on the x-axis?

Using `xextent=(time[0] + 0.125, time[-1])` seems to fix this problem. However, I am unsure what variable determines the bin width, and therefore concerned this might change with other datasets of different sampling rate, number of points, etc.

[image]

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import signal

time = np.linspace(-1, 16, 65536)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * time)

fig = plt.figure()

ax_top = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax_spec = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax_top.plot(time, signal)
ax_top.set_xlim(-1, 10)
ax_spec.set_xlim(-1, 10)

Pxx, freqs, bins, cax = ax_spec.specgram(signal, NFFT=2048, Fs=4096, noverlap=2048 / 2, mode='magnitude', pad_to=2048 * 16)

ax_spec.set_xticks(np.arange(time[0], time[-1], 1))
ax_top.set_xticks(np.arange(time[0], time[-1], 1))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Show the plotting code. You can make your x-data whatever you want

Comment: This seems like a dumb question but Bins is the output of the spectrogram function, which is then being plotted on the x-axis. But how do I modify the bins array before it is plotted? Ideally I would subtract 1 from the bins array before it is plotted.

Comment: You can plot `bins + time[0]`

Comment: Could you make a [mcve]? So randomly generated dataset, linspace or so for the x-data, and just enough code to make the plot above, without any of the extra stuff? I would like to understand the different elements on the plot before posting an answer.

Comment: Sure thing. 
I have been able to use your advice to shift the spectrogram to the correct location on the x-axis however using mesh=ax_spec.pcolormesh(bins+time[0], freqs, 10 * np.log10(Pxx)). 

The only problem I have with this is that it creates a very different appearance than the specgram plot.

Comment: I don't think it's the right way. `xextent` is likely the way to go, since it informs `imshow`'s `extent` but I'd like to play with it before answering. Could you post the MCVE above, instead of your project-specific example?

Comment: FWIW, bin width is determined by `(xextent[1] - xextent[0]) / (len(bins) - 1)`

Comment: I've added an example code

Comment: Not really a MCVE (you could have just done a one-liner with np.random.normal or something), but I'll work with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237963/discussion-between-mad-physicist-and-morgs).

Comment: OK. I finally figured it out. Actually writing a meaningful answer now. The general idea is that there are two things feeding into x-extents: the width and location of your time windows, and the size of the pixels.

Comment: Welp, enjoy! That was an interesting lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will simplify your example slightly, with less manual settings to make sure the axes come out correctly out of the box:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = np.linspace(-1, 16, 65536)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * time)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
# In your case, use this instead:
#fig, (ax_top, ax_spec) = plt.subplots(2, 1, constrained_layout=True)

ax.plot(time, 1024 * signal + 1024, c='r')
Pxx, freqs, bins, cax = ax.specgram(signal, NFFT=2048, Fs=4096, noverlap=2048/2, mode='magnitude', pad_to=2048*16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The goal is to get the time axes of the signal and the image co-aligned.

The important part of the spectrogram code is implemented in [`matplotlib.mlab._spectral_helper`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ad95791ac55f0a44c23aa7b66bb256109eceaf02/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L293). Each column in the spectrogram comes from a time window created by [`matplotlib.mlab._stride_windows`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ad95791ac55f0a44c23aa7b66bb256109eceaf02/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L255). A time window is `NFFT` *samples* wide, so the centers of the `n`th time bin is at `0.5 * (time[0] + time[NFFT - 1]) + n * (NFFT - noverlap) * dt`. You can see this computation in [`mlab._spectral_helper`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ad95791ac55f0a44c23aa7b66bb256109eceaf02/lib/matplotlib/mlab.py#L434). The only difference there is that `dt` is assumed to be `1 / Fs`, and the starting point is assumed to be zero.

Going back to the code for [`specgram`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L7598), you can see that `xextent` gets padded with the necessary half-pixel only if you don't set it manually. All in all, this means that your image is simply shifted by `-time[0]`. You can simulate the same shift using `xextent`.

Before I show how to do that, keep in mind that your value of `Fs` is incorrect:

```
>>> 1 / np.diff(time).mean()
3855.0
```

This is happening because `Fs` should be `(len(time) - 1) / (time[-1] - time[0])`, regardless of anything else. You can easily intuit this from a two-sample case. This will be useful when you apply the half-pixel padding to the edges of your extents manually. The padding code below is taken straight from the case where [`xextent = None`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L7598):

```
time = np.linspace(-1, 16, 65536)
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * time)
fs = (len(time) - 1) / (time[-1] - time[0])
half_pixel = 512 / fs   # (NFFT-noverlap) / Fs / 2
half_bin = 1024 / fs  # NFFT / Fs / 2
xextent = (time[0] - half_pixel + half_bin, time[-1] + half_pixel - half_bin)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

ax.plot(time, (fs / 4) * (signal + 1), c='r')
Pxx, freqs, bins, cax = ax.specgram(signal, NFFT=2048, Fs=fs, noverlap=2048 / 2, mode='magnitude', pad_to=2048 * 16, xextent=xextent)
plt.show()
```

And sure enough, the image is perfectly centered on the signal plot, with the ends of the signal sticking out by exactly half a time window beyond the edges of the image:

[image]